# Facebook flash hiding not working on IE

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-canvas

I'm working on a FB canvas app using Flash with 3D graphics. I must embed my SWF with param wmode="direct".

According to [FB documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#hide_flash_callback), when using wmode="direct", FB hides the flash object when displaying a popup/dialog (buy credits, chat, notifications, etc.) and after the popup close, it shows the flash again.

On Chrome and Firefox it works, but on **IE**, after the dialog closes I checked the flash element style and I saw that visibility=visible, but still the flash is still hidden!

I tried several approaches, all with same result:

1. Not using "hideFlashCallback" on FB.init (let FB do it
   automatically)
2. Using "hideFlashCallback":

   ```
   function onFlashHide(params) {  
     if (params.state == 'opened') {  
       hideFlash();  
       FB.Canvas.hideFlashElement(params.elem);  
     } else if (params.state == 'closed') {  
       showFlash();  
       FB.Canvas.showFlashElement(params.elem);  
     }  
   }  
   function hideFlash() {  
     $('#flashContent').css('visibility', 'hidden');  
   }  
   function showFlash() {  
     $('#flashContent').css('visibility', 'visible');  
   }
   ```

Thanks!
Roei

**UPDATE:**
Another reference to FB documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#flash

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IE when calling the FB.ui functions.  The Facebook dialog would open, but when closed Flash would not come back.

I found a trick which solves this.  Before calling to the FB functions, use javascript to set focus to a different HTML element.  After that, the Flash object became visible again when I was done with the Facebook dialog.

```
    // IE9 has a problem where the Flash object won't regain 
// focus if it has focus when the FB UI is called.  To fix this,
// We'll redirect focus before the call.
var lFocus = document.getElementById('focus_target');
lFocus.focus();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: none;` and `display:block` instead of `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`? In past projects I have noticed that IE sometimes has trouble with the `visibility` CSS property...

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. More than that, it didn't work in Chrome too.  Thanks for your post :)